# Category or web API for NSString to pluralize English words?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Is there an open-source category out there that defines a method like `-[NSString pluralizeString]` to pluralize normal English non-proper nouns, checking it against all known exceptions and so on?

Otherwise, is there a free web API that can be used besides Wolfram Alpha that might do the same trick?

Answer (score 7):

check [Active Support Inflector](https://github.com/tomafro/ActiveSupportInflector)